# html image map + jquery maphilight - highlight all areas ids that match values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

I have a simple html image map and a simple array with names of states, i want all the states within the array to be highlighted in the html image map. This is my initial code, all my tries to get reference the area id of the html image map have been unsuccessful:

```
<div id="mapchart">

    <img src ="C:\Users\userA\Desktop\folder\usmap.png" border="0" alt="US Map" usemap ="#usmap" class="maphilight" />
    <map name="usmap">
    <area shape ="poly" id="CO" title="CO" alt="CO" coords ="160, 132, 152, 185, 225, 193, 229, 139" href ="javascript:alert('CO');" />
    <area shape ="poly" id="TX" title="CO" alt="TX" coords ="214, 199, 210, 261, 167, 258, 168, 262, 170, 262, 170, 267, 185, 281, 185, 285, 187, 287, 187, 290, 188, 294, 189, 296, 193, 299, 197, 300, 203, 304, 212, 294, 228, 294, 237, 309, 239, 315, 244, 323, 247, 325, 248, 331, 253, 335, 260, 344, 264, 346, 269, 347, 272, 350, 272, 332, 278,319, 315, 297, 319, 277, 311, 266, 311, 245, 300, 241, 275, 241, 262, 238, 246, 233, 247, 201, 214, 199" href ="javascript:alert('TX');" />

    </map>
    </div>

var states = ["TX", "CO"]; //initially i just want to highlight these 2 states

 $(function () {
           $.each(states, function (index, value) {

                $('.maphilight .TX').maphilight({ alwaysOn: true }); //this doesn't work; i've also tried several variations of this but i'm not able to reference the specific area that matches the corresponding value in the array.

            });

        });
```

Any ideas of how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this same issue, the following worked for me:

```
//initializes maphilight
$(function () {
    $('.maphilight').maphilight({});

    //highlight all values in array
    $.each(states, function (index, value) {

       var data = $('#' + value).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
       data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
       $('#' + value).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `area` tags are children of the `map`, not of the `image`.

You should be selecting `$('map[name=usmap] #TX')`, not `$('.maphilight .TX')`

Answer (score 0):

.maphilight is not an ancestor of .TX.. It's a sibling of the parent..  Also TX is an ID - so you can just pass in the ID selector with the value from the array - Assuming you keep your `ID`'s unique

```
$(function () {
      $.each(states, function (index, value) {
           $('#'+ value).maphilight({ alwaysOn: true }); 
      });
});
```

Comment: Technically, it's not a sibling. More like an aunt.

Comment: @Blazemonger true.. lol didn't see it wrapped in the map element

Comment: wirey, your solution makes sense but it didn't work. Initial code to highlight all areas was:

 $(function () {
        $('.maphilight').maphilight({ alwaysOn: true });
                          
 });

$('.maphilight') actually referencing the class for the img tag -- i tried adding this class to each of the areas and doing it that way but it didn't work either. Any other suggestions? i appreciate the help. Thank you.